# Sharing shapefiles across network for QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I am in a very small office of only three computers using QGIS. We wanted to start using one central repository for our datasets as dropbox is used for main network sharing, but would be to slow syncing large datasets.

So I created a simple homegroup which everyone joined at put all the datasets on my free hard drive.

But when I create a project and save it, and then others open it up it is still asking for links to the shapefiles every time.

I realise it is an inelegant solution at this time!

But I just cant work out while the shapefile paths aren't at least sharing across the computers in the homegroup?

Comment: Could you open up the .qgs file in a text editor and show what the layer elements have as a source?

Answer (score 3):

Try mapping your shared folder as a network drive using the same drive letter on each computer (including your own).

See:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/4026635/windows-map-a-network-drive

This way each QGIS install is looking for the same path e.g. if you map the folder as X: drive QGIS will use the path 'X:\filename.shp'.

Comment: Thank you. I will give that a try now. It weird, the links to the shapefiles work when I open up other peoples maps, but only bad links when anyone else opens my maps and I am the creator of the home group and storage for the datasets.